# glassfish behind proxy is unavailable

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy, glassfish, cas

I am setting up a payara glassfish 5.0 web server. It is sitting behind a proxy, that redirects all requests to my server. I was told that proxy is working properly, but all the requests made to that url don't get to my server. (my server log is empty). When I try to connect to my server from localhost everything works as it should.
My setup is a bit complicated:
I have proxy that redirects traffic to my server, and server is based on CAS SSO, so if user is not authenticated my server should redirect to CAS authentication and CAS redirects user back to my server.
I've been told that proxy is working properly and that there is a problem with my configuration. I tried to install a static application (no database, no cas, just static files) and it works on localhost but when trying to access it by url via proxy i get error 503 service unavailable.

Now I am not sure, is there a problem with Glassfish, my application or the proxy. I have a feeling that proxy is set up the wrong way, but have no way of checking this for now.

I've tried deploying a static html files just to see whether my server returns anything and it doesn't work. I tried turning CAS off and it doesn't work.

```
ProxyPass                        /myapp                             http://1.1.1.1:8080/myapp  
  ProxyPassReverse         /myapp                             http://1.1.1.1:8080/myapp  
  ProxyPass                        /myapp/                            http://1.1.1.1:8080/myapp  
  ProxyPassReverse         /myapp/                            http://1.1.1.1:8080/myapp
```

Am I missing the / on proxypass and proxypassreverse

I expect the service to be available through proxy, but actually it is not.

edit:
firewall was blocking requests outside of my machine. Once I turned off firewall my machine became visible.